# Logging out while following section 8.3 of Hartl's "Rails Tutorial" throws a MissingTemplate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm following Hartl's "Rails Tutorial," and everything's been going pretty well so far. However, I'm stuck on section 8.3. I've triple-checked my code, but testing the logout feature still throws a MissingTemplate error. I could create one in /app/views, but I think that isn't the right fix for this error.

Any help you could give this rookie would be much appreciated. Thank you!

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
end
```

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

    def log_in(user)
        session[:user_id] = user.id 
    end

    def log_out
        session.delete(:user_id)
        @current_user = nil
    end

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end

    def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end
end
```

**the test**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    def setup
        @user = users(:michael)
    end

    test "login with valid information followed by logout" do

    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0

  end

end
```

**the error**

```
ERROR["test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout", UsersLoginTest, 2015-10-07 09:40:37 +0900]
 test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout#UsersLoginTest (1444178437.65s)
ActionView::MissingTemplate:         ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template sessions/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
          * "/home/computer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
          * "/home/computer/Workspace/sample_app/app/views"
          * "/home/computer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"

            test/integration/users_login_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

  20/20: [=================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.60698s
20 tests, 45 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Do you have a `redirect_to` in your `destroy` method in `sessions_controller.rb`?

Comment: That fixed it. I accidentally put the`destroy` method in the `users_controller`. If you make this a reply I'll mark it as answered, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's trying to automatically render a template for the `destroy` action in `sessions_controller.rb`, you're probably missing your `redirect_to` in that action's method.